# PhalconPHP and AngularJS on Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to run a combination of PhalconPHP and AngularJS of a Nginx webserver with the following file structure:

```
/root
  /api
    index.php
  index.html
```

PhalconPHP is located in the API folder and needs different rewrite rules then AngularJS.
I've tried to setup a virtual host in Nginx with the following configuration:"

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    listen 80; ## Listen on port 80 ##
    server_name example.com;  ## Domain Name ##
    root /home/vagrant/example.com/angular/build;  ## Site root for the Angular code ##

    index index.html index.php;  ## Set the index for site to use ##

    charset utf-8; ## Set the charset ##

    location / { ## Handle default requests ##
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;  ## Try files and fall back to index.html ##
    }

location /api { ## URL string to use for api ##
    ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
    if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    ## If we get here then there is no file or directory matching request_filename ##
    rewrite (.*) /api/index.php?_url=$query_string;

    ## Normal php block for processing ##
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}


    ## Don't fail or log request to favicon or robots.txt ##
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    ## Access log is off and error log location is set ##
    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    ## Disable sendfile ##
    sendfile off;

    ## Normal php block for processing ##
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    ## Don't allow access to .ht files ##
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I got this from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/deploy-laravel-and-angular-on-same-domain)

I managed to get AngularJS working but unfortunately when I navigate to /api nothing is showing up (just a blank page).
I tried changing some parts of the virtual host rules but with no result (The config posted above it actually the slightly changed one in which I changed the location /api part:

```
location /api { ## URL string to use for api ##
    ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
    if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    ## If we get here then there is no file or directory matching request_filename ##
    rewrite (.*) /api/index.php?_url=$query_string;

    ## Normal php block for processing ##
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now, for people that are also struggling with this, this is the solution:

```
    server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mydomain.com wwww.mydomain.com;
    root /path/to/website/files/public_html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        index index.php;

        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        ## If we get here then there is no file or directory matching request_filename ##
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?_url=/$1 last;

        ## Normal php block for processing ##
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        }
    }
}
```

Feedback is welcome though :D

Answer (score 0):

you can disable  fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
if you dont use https/ssl

if you use  fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
browser redirect to https://

this is fina configuration

> ```
> server_name mydomain.com wwww.mydomain.com;
> root /path/to/website/files/public_html;
> index index.html;
>
> location / {
>     try_files $uri /index.html;
> }
>
> location /api {
>     index index.php;
>
>     ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
>     if (-f $request_filename) {
>         break;
>     }
>
>     ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
>     if (-d $request_filename) {
>         break;
>     }
>
>     ## If we get here then there is no file or directory matching request_filename ##
>     rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?_url=/$1 last;
>
>     ## Normal php block for processing ##
>     location ~ \.php$ {
>         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
>         fastcgi_index index.php;
>         include fastcgi_params;
>         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
>        # fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
>     }
> } }
> ```